# change font of contextmenu in radGridView when filter a column

Tags: c#, filter, telerik, contextmenu, radgridview

When you filter a column on radGridview , a context menu is displayed,which contains a list of items like "No Filter","Contains", "Is Null", "Not Null","Start with" ,"custom" and ...

I wan to change font of it. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the font in `ContextMenuOpening` event:

```
void radGridView1_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs e)
{
    e.ContextMenu.Font = new Font("Arial", 11);
}
```